# SQL - SSIS packages stopped working after restarting SQL server agent(Wrong password errors)

Tags: ssis, proxy

I have restarted SQL server agent , and after that , suddenly , My jobs that run SSIS packages started to fail with the error : reason: Error authenticating proxy <Mydomain_and_user>, system error: The user name or password is incorrect.

I have a proxy account running the SSIS packages but cannot see any reason why its credentials will suddenly be changed.

1. Can someone figure out possible rout cause?
   2.Is there any workaround for that problem without changing my active Directory account password?

Answer (score 1):

OK,I found the old username's password , applied it , and all become ok. I learned that the new SQL agent service didn't have permissions to activate the SSIS proxy user, therefore, one problem caused the other one.
Another thing that I've learned is that SQL service credentials shouldn't be mad using the SERVICES , it should be done only from SQL configuration manager.